# Find equation of parabola, given Focus and equation of directrix

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

I have this problem:

> Write the equation of the parabola, if Focus $F(3,0)$ and equation of directrix is $x-3=0$

help me

Comment: Use http://www3.ul.ie/~rynnet/swconics/eccentricity1.htm

Comment: According to your equations, the focus lies on the directrix, so the solution is simply the line $y=0$.

Comment: So, equation of the parabola is $y=0$?

i know formula $y^2=2px$

but why is focus(3,0) and directrix=3 is in the same place?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#General_case